# Save values beyond control structures

Tags: haskell

Question: is there a way to "store" values beyond control structures

Disclaimer: the following code framework is without any true sense -> it's only for better understanding the question...

The control structure could do "anything" -> that's the reason why I don't want to return  values like the structure would be a normal function...

-> in this case you also can't just call the foo function recursive with changed values cause the foo function would have to jump then into the control structure where it left... etc...

```hs
foo = do
  val1 <- return 2
  val2 <- return 0

  _ <- if True then do
      val1 <- return 3
      (...)
      val2 <- return 6
      (...)
      return () 
    else
      return ()

  _ <- putStrLn $ show(val1) ++ show(val2)

  return ()
```

Comment: Haskell isn't Python. Stripping away scope seems like an ungood idea...

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `IORef` or `STRef`?

Comment: Looking at your pseudocode: What if the `else` branch of the `if` is taken? Then `val1` and `val2` haven't been defined - how would you `show` them?

Comment: Note that the point about the `else` branch is exactly why you should *want* to do this by returning values, not trying to bind variables inside the control structure and use them outside. The type system then *ensures* that you return something of the right type on every branch of your control structure (and will ensue that you continue to do so when you change this code in future).

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [State monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State.html):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data MyState = MyState { val1 :: Int, val2 :: Int } deriving (Eq, Show)

foo :: State MyState String
foo = do
  put $ MyState { val1 = 2, val2 = 0 }
  if True
    then do
      modify (\s -> s { val1 = 3 })
      -- ...
      modify (\s -> s { val2 = 6 })
    else
      return ()
  MyState v1 v2 <- get
  return $ show v1 ++ show v2
```

GHCi:

```
*Q55856229> runState foo $ MyState 0 0
("36",MyState {val1 = 3, val2 = 6})
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want something like this. Remember that `<-` is binding, not assignment, so you can't redefine a variable.

```
foo = do   
  (val1, val2) <- if True then do
      val1 <- return 3
      (...)
      val2 <- return 6
      (...)
      return (val1, val2) 
    else
      return (2, 0)

  _ <- putStrLn $ show(val1) ++ show(val2)

  return ()
```

If you absolutely must have mutating variables, then you need either something like `IORef`, `STRef` or perhaps a `State` monad or `StateT` transformer. Hard to tell with the information the OP posted.